# How can I get the same string between php and nodejs by function longArrayToString

Tags: php, node.js, unicode, hex, ascii

I use xxtea algorithm to comunicate between php and nodejs, but can't get the same result when **transfer a long array to string**.

I've tried to print the length of result string in nodejs and php, both are 4, but when I read file which write by nodejs, it's length become to 6. I used to open two files in hex mode, php file showed the right hex string  **"6C 11 F0 B8"**, but in nodejs it's **"6C 11 C3 B0 C2 B8"**. It seems caused by difference between **ascii** and **unicode**.

**So I wonder to know how can I get the same result between them by modifying the longArrayToString function in nodejs**

```php
<?php
$a = [-1192226452];
$b = long2str($a);
var_dump($b);
file_put_contents('./a.txt', $b);

function long2str($v) {
    $len = count($v);
    $n = ($len - 1) << 2;
    $s = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        var_dump($v[$i]);
        $s[$i] = pack("V", $v[$i]);
        for($j = 0; $j < strlen($s[$i]); $j ++) {
            var_dump(ord($s[$i][$j]));
        }

    }
    return join('', $s);
}
```

```js
const fs = require('fs');

a = [-1192226452];
b = longArrayToString(a);
console.log(b);
fs.writeFile('./b.txt', b, function(error){});

function longArrayToString(data) {
    let length = data.length
        , n = (length - 1) << 2;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        console.log(data[i]);
        data[i] = String.fromCharCode(
            data[i] & 0xff,
            data[i] >>> 8 & 0xff,
            data[i] >>> 16 & 0xff,
            data[i] >>> 24 & 0xff
        );
        for(j = 0; j < data[i].length; j ++)
        {
            console.log(data[i][j].charCodeAt());
        }
    }
    return data.join("");
}
```

**php console result :**
int(-1192226452)
int(108)
int(17)
int(240)
int(184)
string(4) "l�"
**nodejs console result:**
108
17
240
184
lð¸

---

**php file in hex mode:**
6C 11 F0 B8
**nodejs file in hex mode:**
C 11 C3 B0 C2 B8

Answer (score 0):

Technique below gives `.txt` file with bytes (hex): `6C 11 F0 B8`.
The `.toString(16)` part converts your int value to a hex string (eg: `int 108 == hex 6C`).
So just append each hex text to a final/output string using `+=`.

1) Create a temp variable that will hold your final hex string. *eg:* `var num_as_HexStr = "";`

2) Second For-loop does the appends: `num_as_HexStr += (data[i][j].charCodeAt()).toString(16);`

3) Now you can write `num_as_HexStr` (instead of writing `b` to file). The expected hex will be correct.

```
const fs = require('fs');

var num_as_HexStr = "";

a = [-1192226452];
b = longArrayToString(a);

console.log("var b is: " + b);
console.log("var num_as_HexStr is: " + num_as_HexStr);

fs.writeFile('./b.txt', num_as_HexStr, function(error){});

function longArrayToString(data) {

    let length = data.length, n = (length - 1) << 2;

    console.log("string check 1");
    for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        console.log(data[i]);
        data[i] = String.fromCharCode(
            data[i] & 0xff,
            data[i] >>> 8 & 0xff,
            data[i] >>> 16 & 0xff,
            data[i] >>> 24 & 0xff
        );

        console.log("string check 2");
        for(j = 0; j < data[i].length; j ++)
        {
            console.log(data[i][j].charCodeAt());
            num_as_HexStr += (data[i][j].charCodeAt()).toString(16);
            //console.log("hex string: " + num_as_HexStr);
        }
    }
    return data.join("");
}
```